# Жители Монако

Tags: грамотная-речь

А как называются жители Монако? Я могу допустить, что - монакцы, но как тогда назвать жительниц?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жители Монако - монегаски. 
Может быть, он - монегаск, а она - монегаска?

Comment: Монегаски- коренные жители Монако. Их не так много. А жители Монако - монакцы (это и монегаски, и французы, и др. жители). Он - монакец. А вот ж.род  общие словари почему-то не дают. Может. в каком-нибудь специализированном справочнике есть?

Answer (score 0):

Я не сталкивался с обоcнованием, что монегаск - только "коренной" житель **города** или коммуны Монако. Во всех известных мне случаях используется классический этнохороним монегаск.

А вот в отношении **страны** (княжества) Монако действительно наблюдаются колебания. Но не могу подтвердить (или опровергнуть), что "монакец" или что-то подобное является правильным. "Монакец" (только м. и мн.) встречается у Лопатина, но этот словарь просто фиксирует орфографию, нормативность употребления - не его задача, подходящих профильных словарей у меня под рукорй нет. Во всяком случае "монегаск" и тут преобладает и безусловно нормативен.